# facebook access token working on one page only

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii, facebook-php-sdk

My app which was working fine for last 3 months, has encountered a new problem due to some changes in Facebook. When i get access token by:

```
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

it returns a valid token and fetches user info. But on another page i again use the same function to get access token and i get invalid access token including app Id.
i tried to get access token and save it to session and use on another page , but it shows an exception `OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`
but token is valid , i have checked it  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token)

may "[dec 5 , 2012 changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)" be the  reason for this?
i think on my application token is valid for less than a minute.
Please help me.

code-->

```
$facebook = Yii::app()->facebook;
try {
    $facebook_uid = $facebook->getUser(); 

    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');

 }catch(Exception $e) {

     $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_396582000367255_access_token'];
     $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
 }
```

Comment: Is it related to *"We will only allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10 minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be short lived and single use". For more information, check out our Authentication documentation."*?

Comment: Please detail some code, something tells me the access token is appearing as `nil` on the new page.

Comment: my_app_id|3e65ac73b567b54e2c6f6a5b186a71aa it is the token format.

Comment: You cannot use an app token on a `/me` call...

Comment: @phwd i have aceess token on new page also but problem in fetch user info by $facebook->api('me');

Comment: i check it without access token and it throws exception

Comment: `You cannot use an app token on a /me call` You must use a user access token.

Comment: It could be related to this http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13744673/facebook-php-sdk-misbehaving-after-december-12-updates

Comment: @Waleed Khan [Authentication documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) is redirecting to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. Things where alittle out of order and you were setting the token in an else switch of the try catch.

```
$facebook = Yii::app()->facebook;
try {
    $facebook_uid = $facebook->getUser(); 
     $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_396582000367255_access_token'];
     $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
    //$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');

 }catch(Exception $e) {


 }
```

Comment: worked once, but still getting error "Undefined index: fb_396582000367255_access_token "

Comment: you need to use the current version of php-sdk

Comment: i would also suggest removing the wrapper

Comment: i have updated sdk and updated the wrapper, new extension can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/hemendra619/yii-facebook-opengrpah)

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/404450666302585 but you can use Shawn Carter's work around.  If you do use his workaround you need to prevent the Facebook SDK from clearing the session.  That's the reason your only getting it to work once.  A crude and very dirty way of doing this is to modify the facebook.php method for clearing all persistant data.

```
protected function clearAllPersistentData() {
  return;
  foreach (self::$kSupportedKeys as $key) {
      $this->clearPersistentData($key);
  }
}
```

In addition for it to work for others (who's sessions aren't set) you'll need to allow facebook to do its thing once.  So what I'm doing is:

```
$tok = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if(strpos($tok, $config["appId"]) == 0 && isset($_SESSION["fb_" . $config["appId"] . "_access_token"]))
{
    $facebook->setAccessToken($_SESSION["fb_" . $config["appId"] . "_access_token"]);
    $tok =$_SESSION["fb_" . $config["appId"] . "_access_token"];
}
```

Mind you this is all very dirty.  Since you've muddied up the water with the clearing session thing you'll need to also clear the session yourself to handle other auth situations like user logging out, removing then adding your app back, etc... etc...  So while you can do this in the short term till they fix the SDK don't leave it in your code.

Comment: Just FYI this has been fixed so you shouldn't be doing this anymore =)

Answer (score 1):

Try fb**sr**_396582000367255_access_token instead fb_396582000367255_access_token